# jQuery Mobile Custom Buttons - General CSS Issue

Tags: css, button, jquery-mobile, imagebutton

I am having a slight issues with CSS and jQuery Mobile, I am trying to add custom icons to buttons but the code does not seem to work. The page can be found here: 
[Link to Website](http://joelharley.com/v2/#findus)

A funny issue is when you load the website in Firefox and then hit "Edit CSS" the icons suddenly appear... Not sure what the issue is.

Many Thanks, 
Joel

Comment: I get a 404: http://joelharley.com/v2/css/images/buttonIcons/phone.png and http://joelharley.com/v2/css/images/buttonIcons/email.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The images were linked incorrectly.